# I Have Problem to In understanding this query

Tags: mysql

What does `(:Id)` mean here tomorrow I have presentation about this I'm but I have problem here

```
select first_name, last_name from users where user_id= (:id) limit 1
```

Comment: `:id` is a *named parameter* (the parentheses don't make sense in that context), that can be use in parameterized queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is parameterized query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query)